# No module named 'discord'

Tags: python, discord

I'm creating a discord bot, but when I try to import `discord`, I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Someone\Desktop\Discord bot\bot.py", line 2, in <module>
    import discord
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'
[Finished in 0.5s]
```

I opened a terminal <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd> and typed:

```
pip install discord.py
```

And I have got this error:

```
  File "<string>", line 1
    pip install discord.py
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: have you tried https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/
$ git clone https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py
$ cd discord.py
$ python3 -m pip install -U .[voice]

Comment: Yes, and i've got the same error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you wrote the pip command into a Python prompt instead of the OS terminal

Answer (score 3):

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>~</kbd> (actually <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd>) "terminal" isn't actually a command line terminal, it's a Python REPL. Open the command prompt in Windows by hitting <kbd>Win</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, then typing `cmd` and hitting Enter. `pip install discord.py` should now install `discord.py` and all of its dependencies.