# invalid syntax error (discord.py) it would be nice if you could fix

Tags: python, discord.py

Whenever I try and install discord.py with pip it does this:

```
>>> pip install discord.py
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

with the word install highlighted in red. Please help.

Comment: You need to use pip in the terminal, not in the python launcher. Type `pip install discord`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No module named 'discord'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67121563/no-module-named-discord), it was asked yesterday but that might be a coincidence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pip is a program that installs modules to be used by Python and should be run from the command line, not from the Python interpreter.

Once you have installed a module you can import it from within the Python interpreter.